# Three.js - FBX Import or Online Conversion

Tags: sdk, three.js, webgl, fbx

I know the sites studio.verold.com and sketchfab.com and  p3d.in they have found a way to import .fbx.
Have anyone a hint how they did this ?
I thought 1st it must todo with the autodesk fbx sdk and python.
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/converters/fbx
But i ended up in a offline conversion .
I am thankful for any help

Comment: http://area.autodesk.com/blogs/chris/serving_webgl_content_using_the_fbx_python_sdk
Could this be this way with a Phyton Webserver ?

Comment: http://verold.com/blog/2012/11/27/designing-the-fbx-converter-for-threejs

Comment: try http://assimp.sourceforge.net/, you can run it from command line tool

Answer (score 2):

You can always use http://Clara.io to do your conversion from FBX to ThreeJS format. :)
-ben

Comment: Upvoted as this was useful for me last week, used clara.io happily to do one such conversion so thanks Ben :)

Comment: But you did not actually answer the question! Which is about how it is done. I'm also curious and asking whether you could disclose some of that: are you using the open source three.js converter tool that uses the Autodesk FBX SDK's Python bindings? Or have some own different solution for some reason?

(meant this in the original comment but pressed enter too early and then SO didn't let me edit the comment anymore, urgh)

Comment: We wrote our own over the last two years using the Autodesk FBX SDK and Python -- the FBX format is just brutal to handle though.  We are still fixing conversion issues with various weird FBXs every week.  We've done around 10,000 FBX file conversions I believe.  You can use our converter via the Clara.io REST API if you want: https://clara.io/learn/sdk/api/export

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the Assimp commandline converter. Three.js now has a parser for the binary Assimp format. This is how we do it at [Virtulous](https://virtulo.us), and it's working pretty well for us. If you're interested in efficiency, you can create your own Assimp exporter module, and only export the data channels you need.